# exec perl regexp one liner from tclsh

Tags: perl, tcl

I want to modify an ASCII file.
Each line contain

```
XOR word word
```

should be changed to

```
my insertion XOR word word
```

for this task I am using simple PERL one liner

```
perl -i -pe "s/(XOR\s.*)/my insertion (\1)/g" testFile
```

and it works perfect in tcsh
but when I execute it from tclsh the file not modified

```
tcsh> cat testFile

some text
XOR X1 Y2
another line
yet another line
XOR X2 Y3
something else


tclsh:
%catch {exec perl -pe "s/(XOR\s.*)/my insertion (\1)/g" testFile} res 
0
puts $res

some text
XOR X1 Y2
another line
yet another line
XOR X2 Y3
something else
```

Comment: -i flag in tclsh example is not matter since I get the output in res variable.

BTW, even adding -i not modified the testFile

Comment: In perl, use `$1` instead of `\1` in the replacement part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to brace the expression.

```
exec perl -i -pe {s/(XOR\s.*)/my insertion (\1)/g} testFile
```

Or, escape the backslashes. Because, within double quotes, `\s` is same as literal `s`. To represent the literal backslash, it should be

```
exec perl -i -pe "s/(XOR\\s.*)/my insertion (\\1)/g" testFile
```

Comment: I am not a `perl` expert. But, giving answers from the `tcl`'s perspective.

Comment: It works! Thanks! but what if I'll use variable instead string. In this case regexp inside {} will not be parsed.

Comment: @RomanKaganovich : Then you should use double quotes only and escape the backslashes accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

For reference, a pure-Tcl solution.

```
package require fileutil

proc rsub {str data} {
    regsub -all -line {^(XOR)\y} $data "$str \\1"
}

::fileutil::updateInPlace testfile [list rsub "my insertion"]
```

Documentation: [fileutil](http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/fileutil/fileutil.html) package, [list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm), [package](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/package.htm), [proc](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/proc.htm), [regsub](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You don't show the critical `-i` flag *in your tcsh script* (the command you show has it) -- to change the file in place.  So if this is indeed in your script, you are not telling it to write the file.

Additionally, I'd change the one liner to prepend to the line instead of running the substitution.

```
perl -i -ne 'print "my insertion " . $_ if /^XOR/' testFile
```

---

**Added** after the fact, for completeness.

As shown in [Dinesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/974155/dinesh) solution, code inside `''` need also be wrapped in `{}` for protection.

Comment: % exec perl -ne 'print "my insertion " . $_ if /^XOR/' testFile
can't read "_": no such variable

Comment: @RomanKaganovich I see -- then you need to protect the arguments (`exec perl args`) from shell interpretations.  I'll look into how exactly to do this. It may be even enough to escape a few characters, but it's better to protect the whole expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `-i` for modify the file itself

```
 perl -i -pe  "s/(XOR\s.*)/my insertion (\1)/g" testFile
```

Comment: thanks for your comment but it exactly what i do when running pure perl from shell